# How to use cacheIdentity in dynamic block graphql in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.4, cache, dynamic-blocks

I want to use cache in dynamic block graphql with cacheIdentity.
I have added this into the graphql where I am getting the dynamic blocks data in the graphql response.

But how can I check weather the data is cached or not for the dynamic block?
Can anyone suggest the process to implement the cache?

Comment: You can check the caching process in Magento's own CMS blocks in vendor folder, that are easy starting points to understand the process. To check whether your data indeed is getting cached or not, log the IDs generated in a file, which you can then check in your Redis directly with queries.